# apps script getValue contents only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following that works fine:

```
function phototable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('####');
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange('H'+lastRow)
  .setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/####/edit","Form Responses!U:Z"),4,false)');
}
```

However, I don't want the formula copied into column `H`, just the actual value. So I tried:

```
ss.getRange('H'+lastRow)
  .getValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit","Form Responses!U:Z"),4,false)')
  .copyTo('H'+lastRow,{contentsOnly:true});
```

But that doesn't insert anything into column H. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `I have the following that works fine:`, when I saw the above script, I think that an error occurs at `getValue`. Because `getValue` has no arguments. I thought that `getValue` was `setValue`.
- At `copyTo('H'+lastRow,{contentsOnly:true})`, the 1st argument is the range object.
- In order to copy the result of the formula during the script as the string, it is required to use `flush`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function phototable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('####');
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange('H'+lastRow);
  range.setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit","Form Responses!U:Z"),4,false)');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

#### Note:

- In your script, `ss` is the 1st tab of the Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Answer (score 1):

### **Issues / Explanation:**

You have 2 ways to update the cell in column H with the value of the formula:

1. If you want to update the cell in H with its value then get the value and set it back:

   ```
   range.setValue(range.getValue());
   ```
2. Use the [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options) method:

   ```
   range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true});
   ```

As a bonus information, [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options) can not be used if the source range and the target range are not of the same spreadsheet file.

- Since this process happens really fast, it is a good idea to use [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) for the pending sheet changes to be completed.

---

### **Solution:**

```
function phototable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('####').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange('H'+lastRow);
  range.setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/####/edit","Form Responses!U:Z"),4,false)');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.setValue(range.getValue());
  // range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true}); // choose this or the previous line
}
```

Modify `Sheet1` to the name of the sheet you want to apply this operation.

- Also it is a better practice to choose a particular sheet before you apply any function to it. To get a sheet by its name use [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).